# use vi/zathura bindigs with calibre viewer

Tags: calibre

I have used zathura for ebook viewing in the past. I accidentally stumbled upon the calibre ebook-viewer after downloading the editor and I quite like the extra functionality it offers. However, I can not get used to the keybindings. I have been able to map the main ones (like scroll and search) to the analogs used in zathura, but it's still a bit clunky. Is there some way to get vim/zathura-like bindigs in calibre?